# Retrieving Java package name of AIDL consumer

Tags: android, aidl

I am exposing some API through [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/guide/components/aidl.html) mechanism. Clients need to bind to the AIDL and call methods synchronously. Is there a way I can retrieve the client's Java package name?

For example, if I expose a method `boolean isFooAvailable()` as AIDL API, from within the implementation of isFooAvalable, can I determine the Java package name of the app that binds to the AIDL service?

Comment: `Binder.getCallingUid()` should be able to give you the Linux UID of the caller. From there, `PackageManager` can help you track down the app(s) that use that UID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can find out the package name from within the implementation as follows :

```
IAidl.Stub mBinder = new IAidl.Stub() {

    @Override
    public boolean isFooAvailable() throws RemoteException {

       String pkgName = "";
        int pid = Binder.getCallingPid();

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo proc : processes) {

            if (proc.pid == pid) {

                pkgName = proc.processName;
            }
        }
       // package name of calling application package
       Log.e("Package Name", pkgName);
       return false;
    }
}
```

Finding package name through PID is the best approach compared to UID.

Comment: `getRunningAppProcesses()` has a note "this method is only intended for debugging or building a user-facing process management UI" -- it may not be suitable to use it here.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the comment given by CommonsWare, inside your `Service` you can use

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
String callingName = packageManager.getNameForUid(Binder.getCallingUid());
```

If you're trying to restrict access to of callers you should also check the certificates of the calling app.

```
PackageInfo callingPackageInfo = packageManager
  .getPackageInfo(callingPackage, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
// Make sure to check there is only one signature, or you may run into a security
// vulnerability: https://androidvulnerabilities.org/vulnerabilities/Fake_ID
verify(callingPackageInfo.signatures);
```